# Use tf.nn.local_response_normalization in keras layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using keras to add layers, for example:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(16, 16, 32)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

Now I am implementing LRN. However, the keras library does not have LRN to my limited knowledge. The old tf.nn library does have a LRN function called tf.nn.local_response_normalization.

Is it possible to mix tf.nn with keras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`tf.nn.local_response_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/local_response_normalization) can be used in a lambda layer. See the code below:

```
...
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.add(layers.Lambda(tf.nn.local_response_normalization))
...
```